# Fast Report in Delphi 11. How to print each record based on the Quantity field of the record

Tags: delphi, report, pascal, fastreport

I have a master Detail report.
I want the report to print the master information (With its details) based on its quantity field.
So if the Quanitty field of master record is 3 it should show up 3 times on the report if the Field is 2 it should come up 2 times etc.

-Here is an example of a Master table with 2 records

Master 1 Quantity field is 3,
Master 2 Quantity Filed is 2

The desired Print is as follows:

Master1
Detail1

Master1
Detail1

Master1
Detail1

Master2
Detial2

Master2
Detail2

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Use a FrxDBUserDataset
[image: FastReport Design]
[image: Form Design and Run]
Code

```
procedure TForm16.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
frxreport1.ShowReport();
end;


// IMPORTANT  frxUserDetail.RangeEnd:=reCount
procedure TForm16.frxDBMasterFirst(Sender: TObject);
begin
frxUserDetail.First;
frxUserDetail.RangeEndCount:=FDMaster.FieldByName('QTE').AsInteger;
end;

procedure TForm16.frxDBMasterNext(Sender: TObject);
begin
frxUserDetail.First;
frxUserDetail.RangeEndCount:=FDMaster.FieldByName('QTE').AsInteger;
end;
```

My SQL data (Firebird) was

```
SELECT CAST('LIGNE 1' AS VARCHAR(20)) DESCRIPTION,3 QTE FROM RDB$DATABASE
UNION
SELECT CAST('LIGNE 2'  AS VARCHAR(20)),1 FROM RDB$DATABASE
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, But I want to print the Maser and the details 3 times so i.e.
Master 1

Comment: I updated my initial Question to clarify. Pleas take a look. :)

Comment: If you look at my response, you can see that the data printed  ('LIGNE 1', 'LIGNE 2') are from Master Datasource, so I don't understand your problem.
I think you simplified your problem, perhaps because detail data are missing ?

Comment: I'm not sure I'm getting what the RangeEndCount Property is... Can you please elaborate?

Comment: Also, I see in your Frx screenshot that Ligne 1 is actually in the DetailsData in Frx this is not the case in my situation where want the master data to be printed based on the Quantity...

Comment: frxUserDetail is a TfrxUserDBUserDataset. RangeEndCount is the property used to give the number of "pseudo" records so the number of lines you want repetead. Think about detail band as a loop  

"Ligne 1" as you ask is in the Details Data yes, but from Master Data as Said by Fabrizio in a détail databand you can put master and détail data.

Comment: So Why Can't I put the Master in the master band and details in the details band, and then set `onfirst` and `onNext` of FrxDbDsMaster the RangeEndCount of Master to quantity I desired? Instead of putting it on the detail...

Answer (score 0):

You can do as follows:

1. Add a master band and link it to the master dataset.
2. Set the master band height to 0
3. Add a detail band and put the fields from both master and detail datasets in this band

[image: Picture showing the FastReport designer with a master band with 0 height, and a detail band]

Comment: I don't think your response complied. In the question, codeGood want 3 lines.
When I use this sort of thing, i.e for box'labels, I work on the data (memtable) before printing (in this case generating 3 records)